RegionMeasure gives finite answer for infinite measure?
I give Mathematica the following command:
    RegionMeasure[
ImplicitRegion[0 <= z < (x y)/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + x^2) (-4 + y^2)] && x >= 2 && y >= 2, {x, y, z}]]

The answer should be infinite, but Mathematica gives the answer $3/2$. What is it doing here? If I put upper bounds on $x$ and $y$ it gives the correct answer.
To confirm
Integrate[(x y)/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + x^2) (-4 + y^2)], {x, 2, Infinity}, {y, 2, Infinity}]

Does say the integral does not converge.

This has the same bug: Integrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] reg]. Changing the order of the variables to, say, {z, x, y} yields the right answer.

Mathematica v12.2 gives correct answer!

This bug was introduced from version 13.
